# Hibernate reading from but not writing to database. In memory is fine

Tags: hibernate

I've migrated our Hibernate5/Oracle12c web application from Glassfish 4 to Tomcat 9.

The application works as long as Tomcat is running.  It reads preexisting data from the database and displays correctly.  It allows new data to be created.  It allows data to be edited.  If I launch a second browser, I see the new and edited data.

But, when I shutdown Tomcat and relaunch it.  All new records and edited data is gone, only fresh reads are there.  I'm new to Hibernate, so it could be basic, but I'm finding no help via searches.

Comment: What database system are you using? Is it an in-memory database?

Comment: @AdamP We use Oracle 12c.

Comment: Any relevant code snippets?

Comment: @AdamP Unfortunately the code is at work, and I'm home now.

Comment: HI! I have a same probleb (hibernate+wildfly+mysql). You was find answer on you q?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check **hibernate.ddl-auto** setting on you code. Looks like you are facing the **create-drop** situation.

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto Automatically validates or exports schema DDL
>   to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop,
>   the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed
>   explicitly.
>
> e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

So the list of possible options are,

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.

Comment: Mine is set to validate.